# How to create a azure storage account with minmum TLS version as 1.1 using python post api

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to create an Azure storage account using the python Post API method. I am able to create but unable to find in any azure doc on how to add minimum tls version in the code. I attached the JSON Payload for reference.

```
payload = "{\n        \"sku\": {\n            \"name\": \"Standard_GRS\"\n        },\n        \"kind\": \"StorageV2\",\n        \"location\": \"eastus\",\n        }"


storage_url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/123/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageName?api-version=2018-02-01"
value1 = json.dumps(payload)
```

Anyone can just help in Payload for adding minimum tls version as 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: Perhaps you could add - minimumTlsVersion inside properties in the payload. That's how the ARM template is.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala - Please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2):

As per the official documentation here - [Storage Accounts - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/create#request-body), you need to add - properties.minimumTlsVersion to your payload. Default is TLS 1.0.

[image]